# Возможно ли с помощью "PhoneGap/Cordova" реализовать прямую трансляцию с камеры на сайт?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, phonegap

Здравствуйте.

Возможно ли с помощью "PhoneGap/Cordova" реализовать прямую трансляцию с камеры на сайт? Если да, то как примерно это реализуется? В первую очередь вопрос относится к операционным системам "iOS" и "Android" (хотя "Windows Phone" также оказался бы нелишним).

Заранее благодарю.

P.S.: Если кто-либо владеет ссылкой на Интернет-ресурс с пособием по данному вопросу - буду вдвойне благодарен.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтопик - "Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию."